# Kubernetes RBAC roles with resourceName and listing objects

Tags: kubernetes

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1                                                                                                                    
kind: Role                                                                                                                                                  
metadata:                                                                                                                                                   
  name: p-viewer-role                                                                                                                  
  namespace: pepsi                                                                                                                                  
rules:                                                                                                                                                      
- apiGroups:                                                                                                                                                
  - ""                                                                                                                                    
  resourceNames:                                                                                                                                            
  - p83                                                                                                                                                     
  resources:                                                                                                                                                
  - pods                                                                                                                                                
  verbs:                                                                                                                                                    
  - list                                                                                                                                                    
  - get                                                                                                                                                     
  - watch
```

When we use resourceNames in the Roles, the following command works

```
kubectl get pods -n pepsi p83
```

returns a proper value. However,

```
kubectl get pods -n pepsi
```

returns forbidden. Why doesn't it list p83

### RoleBinding

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1                                                                                                                    
kind: RoleBinding                                                                                                                                           
metadata:                                                                                                                                                   
  name: p-viewer-rolebinding                                                                                                          
  namespace: pepsi                                                                                                                                  
roleRef:                                                                                                                                                    
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io                                                                                                                       
  kind: Role                                                                                                                                                
  name: p-viewer-role                                                                                                                  
subjects:                                                                                                                                                   
- apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io                                                                                                                       
  kind: Group                                                                                                                                               
  name: pepsi-project-viewer                                                                                                                    
  namespace: project
```

Answer (score 6):

This is expected behavior. You have defined a `role` which is scoped to the `namespace` pepsi to `pod` `resources` with specific `resourceName` `p83`.

For `kubectl get pods -n peps` command to work you need to remove the `resourceNames` `p83` from the `Role`

This kind of advanced validation is best handled by [OPA](https://www.openpolicyagent.org) where you can define fine grained policies.

Comment: if you want to give access to groups to their particular resources its a problem. List doesn't work. They have to know what to dump to view it. Defeats the purpose. Why not filter in the output list?

Comment: Well..that's how RBAC works...you can explore OPA for more advanced validations like these

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:
`list`(and `watch`)actually can be restricted by their resource name, and permits list(and `watch`) requests using a fieldSelector of `metadata.name=...` to match a single object (for example, `/api/v1/namespaces/$ns/configmaps?fieldSelector=metadata.name=foo`)

For more details and some tests you can check this link: https://github.com/kubernetes/website/pull/29468

@sftim and @liggitt do offer a lot of help!